# Trying to install SugarCRM on ubuntu server 9.10

Tags: linux, ubuntu, mysql, sugarcrm

I have setup the LAMP servers that came with the ubuntu server 9.10 setup and created a database for sugarcrm. When I enter the database name and user name I get this error

The provided database administrator username and/or password is invalid, and a connection to the database could not be established. Please enter a valid user name and password. (Error: 2003: Can't connect to MySQL server on '192.168.0.188' (111)).

Any tutorial on getting the Mysql setup properly? I think it is not, hence the error. Yes?

Comment: Any progress on this Cubalombian?

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you didn't create a MySQL user for the application.  This is not the same as a system user account.  You can [create a MySQL user manually](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/adding-users.html), or have SugarCRM's installation wizard do it for you.

See the [SugarCRM installation guide](http://www.sugarforge.org/content/installation/) for doing this within the Sugar Setup Wizard.  During database configuration you can specify a different user as the database administrator; select "Define user to create" instead of "Provide existing user" when specifying a database administrator user.

[image]